# Need a USB master for test purpose to help in peripheral design and debug

Tags: usb

Basically, I have an IC that can be used to create a USB host or peripheral. It can also operate in OTG mode. I am using it to learn as much as I can about USB. In this endeavour I am trying to create USB peripheral from it also.

The datasheet and other documentation related to it are quite complex in that the information is scattered about and the design examples are elusive, no example exists to create a USB keyboard or mouse peripheral. It will make things 1000s of times easier if there is a mechanism by which I could send a stanard or class specific descriptor request to a specific endpoint e.g get descriptor request to endpoint 0 or a get report request to endpoint 1 for example and see the response (handshake or result in status packet). I am looking for a PC app that can do this.

Is there an application where for example, I can select what to send (control, interrupt, isochronous or bulk transfer or just custom IN or OUT transaction or some other transaction type) to a USB peripheral and at what address and end point and it shows the result e.g the descriptor returned from endpoint 0 or data received from endpoint 3 IN transaction for example.

Answer (score 0):

If there already is a suitable driver for communicating with your device, I would recommend simply plugging the device into your computer and letting your computer use that driver.  You should look at the traffic using a hardware protocol analyzer like the [Beagle 12](http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/) to see if your device is giving the expected responses.  If your device is not behaving as expected, you can then debug it.

You might also consider using [libusb](http://libusb.info/) to send specific requests to your device and to see the response.  You would need to write some code that calls libusb with your desired parameters.

Comment: The driver does not exist, acutely actually the device itself is not fixed, just bunch of endpoints. I am learning usb using it.